# Remove margin from thumbnails using Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, margin

How do I remove the margin between the thumbnails in Bootstrap grid?
I want the thumbnails to be side by side without the margin...

This is the code used to display the thumbnails.
http://www.bootply.com/rrlpsBWCrx

[Image of how it is right NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESPSi.jpg)

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; display:inline-block;">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail goodPick" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <img src="http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/earthshaker_vert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Earthshaker">
  </a>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; display:inline-block;">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail goodPick" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <img src="http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/earthshaker_vert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Earthshaker">
  </a>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; display:inline-block;">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail goodPick" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <img src="http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/earthshaker_vert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Earthshaker">
  </a>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; display:inline-block;">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail goodPick" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <img src="http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/earthshaker_vert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Earthshaker">
  </a>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; display:inline-block;">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail goodPick" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <img src="http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/earthshaker_vert.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Earthshaker">
  </a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Are the actual images you're using all the same size and are they supposed to stack a particular way? I ask since you're applying `inline-block` to your columns and images.

Answer (score 0):

The Elements had padding: http://www.bootply.com/9X6g2U425y

```
.col-md-1 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

How did I find it? You can right-click an element and press "inspect element". You will be able to see the apllyed styles in your Browsers Developer Tool.